# Sending dynamic variable to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I have a table that is built dynamically with EJS template. I want to pass a dynamic value to a jQuery function when the user clicks on the button.

This is how I'm building my table:

```
<% for(var i=0; i< automated_campaigns.length; i++) { %>

...

<%= automated_campaigns[i].name %>

<td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i>">Activate</button>

</td>

...
<% } %>
```

And this is my jQuery function that handles the click event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.btn').on('click', function(automated_campagin_name) {
    var $this = $(this);
  $this.button('loading');

    $.get( "/automated-campaigns/change_status/" + str(automated_campaign_name), function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });


    setTimeout(function() {
       $this.button('reset');
   }, 8000);
});

</script>
```

How can I send the right campaign_name?

Answer (score 3):

Put the `campaign_name` in a `data-campaign_name` since you are already looping for each of them then access it in jQuery.

```
$('.someElement').data('campaign_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set data-attribute on every button you need:

```
<button type="button" data-cname="<%= automated_campaigns[i].name %>" class="btn btn-danger btn" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i>">Activate</button>
```

Script can looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$('.btn').on('click', function(automated_campagin_name) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cname = $this.data("cname");
  $this.button('loading');

    $.get( "/automated-campaigns/change_status/" + str(cname), function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });


    setTimeout(function() {
       $this.button('reset');
   }, 8000);
});

</script>
```