# Passing dynamic values to a jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

The jQuery plugin is looking for some value to set:

```
$('.toClone_example88888').metalClone({
    position:'after',
    btnClone    : '.btn_toClone_example88888'
});
```

The problem is the class names for the item to be cloned, and the corresponding button will be coming from a database so the values need to be dynamic.

I've tried this and while it did not work, it did not produce any console errors either. What am I missing or is this even possible to do?

I found this SO question and believe it has the same core components ([Sending dynamic variable to jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686294/sending-dynamic-variable-to-jquery)) but applying those same concepts didn't work with my implementation.

```
$('.cloneBtn').on('click', function(){
                var getDestinationOfWhereClonedCopyShouldGo = $(this).data("destinationclone");
    $('#' + getDestinationOfWhereClonedCopyShouldGo).metalClone({
        position:'after',
        btnClone    : '.cloneBtn'
    });
});
```

I also tried this but same this, didn't work but no error message either:

```
var cloneThis = function(){
    $('.cloneBtn').on('click', function(){
        var getDestinationOfWhereClonedCopyShouldGo = $(this).data("destinationclone");
        putCloneHere(getDestinationOfWhereClonedCopyShouldGo);
    });
}
    var putCloneHere = function(element){
    $('#' + element).metalClone({
        position:'after',
        btnClone    : '.cloneBtn'
    });
}
```

Additional HTML as requested:

```
<div id="firstOne">
    <input type="text">
    <select id="m">
        <option value="">--Please Select</option>
        <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="container_body">            
    <input type="button" class="cloneBtn" value="Create New Copy" data-destinationclone="firstOne">
</div>

<div id="secondOne">
    <input type="text">
    <select id="m">
        <option value="">--Please Select</option>
        <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="container_body">            
    <input type="button" class="cloneBtn" value="Create New Copy" data-destinationclone="secondOne">
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SavageCatHV/6g60kx0r/) (which includes the plugin code).

Comment: Can you give us a example of your HTML that is being dynamically generated?

Comment: @MatheusCuba html has been added.